# Magento 2.4.5: Change price of a particular product on cart update

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

I am using this observer event for updating price for a particular product based n it's attribute value and subtotal but it applying on all products:

```
checkout_cart_save_after
```

My code:

```
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $cart = $observer->getData('cart');
        $quote = $cart->getData('quote');
        // if (!empty($this->cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal())) {
            
        $subTotal = round($this->cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal(), 0); //Current Cart Subtotal

        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $currentPrice = round($item->getProduct()->getPrice(), 2);
            $customProduct = $this->productModel->load($item->getProduct()->getId());

            $price = $currentPrice;
            
            $freeGiftDollarAmount = $customProduct->getData('free_gift_dollar_amount');
            $freeGift = $customProduct->getData('free_gift');

            // $freeGift = $item->getFreeGift();
            
            if ($freeGiftDollarAmount != '' || $freeGiftDollarAmount !== null) {

                if ($subTotal >= 500 && $subTotal <= 1000 && $freeGiftDollarAmount == 31 && $freeGift) {
                    $price = 0;
                } elseif ($subTotal >= 1000 && $subTotal <= 2500 && $freeGiftDollarAmount == 32 && $freeGift) {
                    $price = 0;
                } elseif ($subTotal >= 2500 && $subTotal <= 5000 && $freeGiftDollarAmount == 33 && $freeGift) {
                    $price = 0;
                } elseif ($subTotal >= 5000 && $freeGiftDollarAmount == 34 && $freeGift) {
                    $price = 0;
                } else {
                    $price = $currentPrice;
                }

                // if ($freeGift) {
                //     $price = 900;
                // }

                $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/cartupdate.log');
                $logger = new \Zend_Log();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info('------------');
                $logger->info('freeGift: '. $freeGift);
                $logger->info('currentprice2: '. $price);
                $logger->info('subTotal: '. $subTotal);
                $logger->info('freeGiftDollarAmount: '. $freeGiftDollarAmount);
        
                if ($freeGiftDollarAmount != '') {
                    $item->setQty('1');
                }
                    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                    $item->save();
            }
        }
        $quote->save();
        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
    }
```